# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name at run time in hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, slf4j

Trying my hand at my first hibernate (JPA annotations) console application. And I've been running around in circles trying to sort out dependencies, it feels like I'm trying to build a house of cards in a hurricane. Also, I'm using maven, I was under the impression that that maven is supposed to prevent this type of thing.. Anyways this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.<init>(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:75)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:75)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:124)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.deangrobler.hibernatetest.App.main(App.java:14)
```

And this is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.deangrobler</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HibernateTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
          <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my annotated bean class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.deangrobler.hibernatetest;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * 
 * @author Dean Grobler
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.deangrobler.hibernatetest.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

If I can get some help on this I shall be eternally grateful!

Comment: Please show the annotated bean.

Comment: Can you show your App.java content?

Comment: Updated my question with the annotated bean class

Answer (score 2):

You have two different version dependency for hibernate entity-manager. This will not work. Remove one of them

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
........................

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that, which one would you say I remove?

Comment: Normally you would want the latest of two i.e., 3.6.10.Final

Answer (score 1):

try either deleting your slfj dependency entry in your pom, your force the hibernate dependency to exclude it.  Hibernate wants to use its own.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.FINAL</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

etc.  Add the same exclusions for hibernate-core etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a version conflict in the dependencies for artifact slf4j-log4j12.

You could check the output of "mvn dependency:tree" to check for a conflict.

Comment: Hi Steven,  how do you output this in Netbeans?

Comment: I don't use Netbeans. Eclipse has a "Dependency Hierarchy" view for the pom.xml, which contains the same information. I would assume that Netbeans has something similar.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_72_NewAndNoteworthy#Dependency_display